# 0xc1 BSOD occuring recently (Minidump/XML included)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod, minidumps

i've been having lots of BSODs recently, it comes randomly, i do not know how to fix it, so far i catched 0x1c error, here are the details:

**Problem Signature :**
  Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
  System Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Local Identifier: 1036

**Additional Infromations on this problem :**
  BCCode: c1
  BCP1: FFFFF9801CC60EE0
  BCP2: FFFFF9801CC60723
  BCP3: 00000000005F0118
  BCP4: 0000000000000032
  OS Version: 6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product: 256_1

MiniDump + XML : http://www.mediafire.com/?2qjt4v87knk3wkc

MEMTEST86 Resulted in a PASS, no errors were found.

S.M.A.R.T Attributes
http://content.screencast.com/users/omarrrio/folders/Snagit/media/c08b179f-9d8c-4346-82e4-fbe06c44c0d0/09.16.2013-17.59.png
HDD extended infos
(i need 10Reputaion to post a third link, sorry)

Comment: What tools have you used to verify what it is not?  For example Memtestx86 woudl verify you its not your memory.  Running some basic S.M.A.R.T tests would tell you if the hdd is the cause.  While helpful unless you tell us a little more the dump file won't e of much help.

Comment: Ill get right on it, i am new to these errors, if you could help me and name some usefull tools, ill be more than happy to post any results or details that these tools give me right away, thank you.

Comment: I gave you one suggestion.  I will let you pick the software you want to run.

Comment: Thank you, i ran Memtest86 and it resulted in a pass, no errors found on the RAM, i updated the OP post with a screenshot of HDD Health S.M.A.R.T Attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've activated driver verifier. You got this bugcheck:

**Bug Check 0xC1: SPECIAL_POOL_DETECTED_MEMORY_CORRUPTION**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The Broadcom Wireless driver (bcmwl664.sys) could cause the crash because the nwifi.sys is involved.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SPECIAL_POOL_DETECTED_MEMORY_CORRUPTION (c1)
Special pool has detected memory corruption.  Typically the current thread's
stack backtrace will reveal the guilty party.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff9801cc60ee0, address trying to free
Arg2: fffff9801cc60723, address where one bit is corrupted
Arg3: 00000000005f0118, (reserved)
Arg4: 0000000000000032, caller is freeing an address where nearby bytes within the same page have a single bit error

Debugging Details:
------------------

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xC1_32

SPECIAL_POOL_CORRUPTION_TYPE:  32

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  1

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

IRP_ADDRESS: fffffa800a417a88

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80004b4ec73 to fffff80004abfb80

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!MiCheckSpecialPoolSlop
02 nt!MmFreeSpecialPool
03 nt!ExDeferredFreePool
04 nt!VfIoFreeIrp
05 nt!IovFreeIrpPrivate
06 nt!IopCompleteRequest
07 nt!IopfCompleteRequest
08 nt!IovCompleteRequest
09 nwifi!Dot11DispatchDevCtrl
0a ndis!ndisDummyIrpHandler
0b nt!IovCallDriver
0c nt!IopXxxControlFile
0d nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile
0e nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd


IMAGE_NAME:  nwifi.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xC1_32_VRF_nwifi!Dot11DispatchDevCtrl+18b

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xC1_32_VRF_nwifi!Dot11DispatchDevCtrl+18b

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xc1_32_vrf_nwifi!dot11dispatchdevctrl+18b

    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\bcmwl664.sys
    Image name: bcmwl664.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Jul 01 15:53:54 2011
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me how to conduct a backtrace to obtain the source of this error? i keep getting 0xc1 and 0x50 and 0x4e BSODs

Comment: I looked at the dmp with WinDbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks